# javascript type issue: Uncaught TypeError: Object 0 has no method 'draw'

Tags: javascript, oop, canvas

Just experimenting with JS + canvas and i seem to have hit a wall.
the "aim" of my minimal application is to click at any random place on the canvas, press the draw button and squares draw where you clicked.

coming from an OO background... i (tried) to use OO, which in js i dont fully have the grasp of.

but basically i have a custom Square object

```
function Square(l, w, x, y) {

    this.length = l;
    this.width  = w;
    this.posx   = x - l/2;
    this.posy   = y - w/2;

    //test
    //ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(20,0,0)";
    //ctx.fillRect(this.posx,this.posy,this.length,this.width);


    this.draw = function() {

        ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(20,0,0)";
        ctx.fillRect(this.posx,this.posy,this.length,this.width);

    }
}
```

which i add to an array every time the user clicks...
here is the event handler for when i click on the canvas.

```
function addTo(evt) {

    pos = getMousePos(evt);
    var sq = new Square(50, 50, pos.x, pos.y);
    list.push(sq);

    output.innerText = "("+sq.posx+","+sq.posy+")";
}
```

and here is where i (attempt) to draw the squares.

```
function renderStack() {

    //alert(list);
    canvas.width = canvas.width;
    for(var o in list) o.draw();

}
```

and this is the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object 0 has no method 'draw'
```

i get a similar error trying to access the variables for that object.
It seems that after i add them to the list js forgets about what type they are? - because when i print the array it is full of [Object object]'s

thanks.

Comment: Off topic, but take your `draw` method out of the constructor, and place it once on the `prototype`. `Square.prototype.draw = func...`

Comment: Thanks, new to JS, any good resources for objects especially; I've read some conflicting things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for(var o in list)
```

`o` is the index (or property) of array. You will access what's stored at that index by `list[o]`.

But for the arrays, it is better to use `for` loop as shown by Alnitak than `for-in`.

**Update:**

For-in is to be used when you need to loop through all the properties. Since array is an object it has indices and properties. So for-in will iterate through all the indices and properties. for-in is better for objects.

e.g.

```
var obj = { p1: 1, p2: 2};

for(var prop in obj) {
   //...
}
```

Comment: @cream-corn: See update. This might give some hint on why not for-in for array: http://jsfiddle.net/BGurung/5tbdh/.

Comment: @cream-corn: `for-in` is used for enumeration. In JavaScript it is best not used on Arrays because you'll hit all enumerable properties, and people like to extend Arrays. So you use `for-in` when you want all enumerable properties. You use `for` when you want iteration of indices. This was not the cause of your problem though. The problem was calling `.draw()` on a `key`, instead of using the `key` to get the `value`. The answer you chose has misleading information. This answer is better.

Comment: yes, i now realize this and the error of my ways. thanks all for a speedy reply :)

Answer (score 5):

`for ... in ...` gives you an object's *keys* and not its *contents*.

So on an Array you will receive both the *indices* of the stored elements and the *names* of any other enumerable properties.

Instead, you should use:

```
for (var i = 0; i < list.length; ++i) {
     list[i].draw();
}
```

Comment: An Array is an object. The direct mistake was calling the method on the key (String) instead of the value. Though you're right that it is better to use a `for` statement.

Comment: @amnotiam text fixed - I was writing it in a hurry.